# URL is not a function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, require

I've been trying to use the url module for node js described here: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url, but I can't seem to get the simple examples to work.  I'd like to be able to build a url, but with the following code,

```
const URL = require('url');
const apiUrl = new URL('myapi.com/');
apiUrl.searchParams.set('tickers', tickers);
console.log(apiUrl.href);
```

I run into the error that URL is not a function.  I've tried this with the other way the site suggests initializing URL too, as

```
const { URL } = require('url');
```

But that causes syntax errors on the first open bracket.
How can I use the url module to actually manipulate urls?

Edit:

In light of MinusFour's suggestion, I'm now up to here:

```
const URL = require('url').Url;
const apiUrl = new URL('myapi.com/');
console.log(apiUrl);
apiUrl.search = 'tickers=[\'msft\']';
console.log(apiUrl.href);
```

This does compile and run without throwing an error, but logs

```
Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: null,
  path: null,
  href: null }
null
```

Which isn't really what I had hoped for.

Comment: "But that causes syntax errors on the first open bracket." That's because you are using an old version of node.js. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 5):

It's a property of the module:

```
const URL = require('url').URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node 6.x then you have to use `URL.parse` instead.